# Mysql pagination without offset

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

Let's assume I have got a table with these data:

[image: Table data]

I want to order it by createdAt column DESC, and id column DESC

```
select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC]

I want to paginate it with 2 items per page and, for performance reasons, I don't want to use `offset`, just `limit`:

```
select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc limit 2
```

[image]

To get the next 2 items i use this query:

```
SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt <= '2014-11-16 09:11:03' AND (id < '15' OR createdAt < '2014-11-16 09:11:03') ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC LIMIT 2
```

[image]

I can go on like this. Get the last item's `createdAt` and `id` then use it for `next` page query.

But i'm trying to formulate the `previous page` query for almost two days and can't figure out a way yet.

Here is what i tried already:

Get the first item from current result (instead of last) use it's `id` and `createdAt` field and reverse the conditions in query (`createdAt >=, id >, created at >`). But this query always gives me the first two results (which is normal because the rows providing this conditions are the first two).

I'm already out of ideas. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: In reality, is the dataset much larger than this?

Comment: Yes, it's full of log - analytics data with a couple million rows.

Comment: and what's wrong with offset?

Comment: offset slows it down after a couple of pages. More info: i.imgur.com/Q8ZRKPs.jpg and slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql

Comment: I'd be tempted to ask Rick James (aka superfreak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could order ascending to get the correct records:

```
SELECT id, createdAt 
  FROM post 
 WHERE createdAt >= '2014-11-16 09:11:03' 
   AND (id > '15' OR createdAt > '2014-11-16 09:11:03') ORDER BY createdAt ASC, id ASC
LIMIT 2
```

and the reverse the sorting when displaying the result set.